# Como mudo estado de um atributo de objeto com react Hooks

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Eu tenho o seguinte estado com React Hooks:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState({
    card1: false,
    card2: false,
    card3: false,
    card4: false,
    card5: false,
    card6: false,
    card7: false,
});
```

Gostaria de fazer uma função que recebe um id que seria um card -por exemplo:

```
function Mudar(id) {
     setActive((prevState) => {
       return { ...prevState, id: true };
     });
}

//depois chamo a função passando Mudar("card1") por exemplo
```

mas, ao invés dele mudar o ***card1*** para `true`, por exemplo, ele cria um novo atributo id e coloca para `true`.

Sabem porque isso acontece e como eu posso corrigir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está criando um novo item nesse objeto porque foi assim escrito no código um nome totalmente diferente dos outros e assim ele copia as chaves existentes e cria um id com o valor já mencionado.

O que necessita é o mais básico possível com essa mudança:

```
function Mudar(key) {
     setActive((prevState) => {
       return { ...prevState, [key]: true };
     });
}
```

No momento da criação dos `card`, precisa recuperar o nome dessa chave e passar na função como não foi mencionado a função ou rotina que cria esses `card` talvez fique incompleta nesse aspecto.

Um código exemplo sem saber do seu:

```js
function Card({name, status, click}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {name} - {status ? 'true': 'false'}
      {!status && (<button onClick={click}>Alterar</button>)}
    </div>
  )
}
function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState({
    card1: false,
    card2: false,
    card3: false,
    card4: false,
    card5: false,
    card6: false,
    card7: false,
  });
  function changeCard(key) {
     setActive((prevState) => {        
       return {...prevState, [key]: true};
     });
  }
  return (
    <div>
    {Object.entries(active).map((d,i) => 
        <Card 
            name={d[0]} key={i} 
            status={d[1]} 
            click={e => changeCard(d[0])}
        />)
    }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

Essa maneira como está proposto na sua pergunta não é o ideal, porque, um objeto com várias chaves que são diferentes pelo nome deveria ser um `array` de objetos, um exemplo modificado com a realidade da maioria dos desenvolvimentos para [react](/questions/tagged/react):

```js
function Card({name, status, click}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {name} - {status ? 'true': 'false'}
      {!status && (<button onClick={click}>Alterar</button>)}
    </div>
  )
}
function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState([
    {name: 'card1', status: false},
    {name: 'card2', status: false},
    {name: 'card3', status: false},
    {name: 'card4', status: false},
    {name: 'card5', status: false},
    {name: 'card6', status: false},
    {name: 'card7', status: false},
  ]);
  function changeCard(obj) {
     setActive((prevState) => {          
       return [...prevState.map(a => {
        if (a.name === obj.name) {
          return {...a, status: true};
        }
        return a;
       })];
     });
  }
  return (
    <div>
    {active.map((d,i) => 
        <Card 
            name={d.name} key={i} 
            status={d.status} 
            click={e => changeCard(d)}
        />)
    }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

dessa forma o objeto com a propriedade `name` é a chave unica desse objeto no `array` para alterações, remover etc, *poderia até ser um identificação numérica*, mas, é o suficiente para a demonstração onde a lista de valores as operações são mais simples.